# How to save data in both (user and profile) tables using django signals in a single request?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I have a register form with fields(firstname, lastname, username, email, dateofbirth, phoneno.)

I have used signals to create a record in userprofile. whenever a new userdata is added to the user table

what i want is whenever user post the request. the data should get saved in user table and then the signal creates a record in profile table and then the remaining data should also get populated in there respected fields. As I'm receiving all the data from user at the registration time.

`views.py`

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        print(request.POST)


        first_name = request.POST.get('first-name')            <-----user table
        last_name = request.POST.get('last-name')            <-----user table
        username = request.POST.get('username')            <-----user table
        email = request.POST.get('email')            <-----user table
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')            <-----profile table
        date_of_birth = request.POST.get('date-of-birth')            <-----profile table
        address = request.POST.get('address')            <-----profile table
        phone_number = request.POST.get('mob-number')            <-----profile table

        ans_1 = request.POST.get('ans-1')            <-----profile table
        ans_2 = request.POST.get('ans-2')            <-----profile table

        User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=username, last_login=timezone.now())


    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')
```

`signals.py`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserInformation.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_info(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userinfo.save()
```

`apps.py`

```
class YourappConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
    def ready(self):
        import yourapp.signals
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is a good solution or not. But this work for me.

`views.py`

```
def register_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        new_user  =  User(first_name = request.POST.get('first-name'),
        last_name = request.POST.get('last-name'),
        username = request.POST.get('email-mobile'),
        last_login=timezone.now()
        # password = request.POST.get('password')
        )
        new_user.set_password(request.POST.get('password'))

        new_user.gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        new_user.date_of_birth = request.POST.get('dob')
        new_user.address = request.POST.get('address')

        new_user.ans_1 = request.POST.get('ans-1')
        new_user.ans_2 = request.POST.get('ans-2')
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('auth-login')

    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')
```

`signals.py`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        attrs_needed= ['gender', 'date_of_birth', 'address', 'ans_1', 'ans_2']
        UserInformation.objects.create(user=instance, gender=instance.gender, date_of_birth = instance.date_of_birth, address=instance.address, ans_1=instance.ans_1, ans_2=instance.ans_2)


post_save.connect(create_user_info, sender=User, weak=False)
```

`apps.py`

```
class YourappConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
    def ready(self):
        import yourapp.signals
```

So, what I have done here is I first took all the request data and bind it to `User` object. And then in `signals.py` I took the instance (which is passed with the post_save signal) and then while creating the Userinfo new object I also pass the fields data to it.

Comment: is it possible to write `attrs_needed=` shorthanded like `**validated_data`?

Answer (score 0):

I could have commented but am unable to add a comment to your question.
I reproduced your error but I updated `app.py` by adding the `ready()` function and adding `import yourapp.signals` in the `AppConfig(AppConfig)` class I was able to update the Profile model

```
class YourappConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
    def ready(self):
        import yourapp.signals
```

Comment: actually i have done that  in my code . but i forgot to mention it in my ques.And that was not the problem . Anyway thanx for looking it. I have also posted my ans and posted down .